# How to catch and recover from temporary socket errors in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm running a massive scrape job over HTTP APIs and have already used `Control.Monad.Retry` to allow my to retry the HTTP call if a temporary HTTP errors, such as, `ConnectionTimeout`, `ProxyConnectException`, `ConnectionFailure`).

However, if a socket-level error is raised due to a blip in the network, such as...

```
Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)
```

...the entire process halts because there is no `Handler` in place for whatever this exception is.

I've tried looking at what kind of exceptions the `socket` library uses, and I *think* the function at play is [throwSocketErrorCode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.1.1/docs/src/Network.Socket.Internal.html#throwSocketErrorCode), which internally uses [Foreign.C.Error.errnoToIOError](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-Error.html#v:errnoToIOError).

```
throwSocketErrorCode loc errno =
    ioError (errnoToIOError loc (Errno errno) Nothing Nothing)
```

So, it seems like an `IOError` (type synonym for `IOException` is being raised), which contains an error number inside it as well. I'm **assuming** that the error number will tell me something about the type of exception on the basis of which I will be able to decide whether to retry or abort. However, I couldn't find a way to get the errorNo out of an `IOException`.

**So, how do I catch such network errors and decide whether to retry or abort?**

Comment: Something like `catch operation (\e -> if (ioe_type e == ResourceVanished) then doRetryThing else doFailThing)`

Comment: are the constructors of `IOException` exported? Did I miss that simple thing?

Comment: `Prelude> import GHC.IO.Exception` ...  `Prelude GHC.IO.Exception> :i IOException`   ... Yep, seems to be exported.

Answer (score 1):

There is no “standard” way of doing this, because the `IOException` type is opaque in the standard. However, luckily, its constructor and fields are exported from [`GHC.IO.Exception`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Exception.html#IOException), so you will be able to analyse its `IOErrorType` and errno nevertheless.